# C# SQL multiple query results into diffrent textbox

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

So I'm having this :

```
            Conn.Open();
            SqlCommand Comm3 = new SqlCommand("SELECT answer" + " FROM answers" + " WHERE id_answer=5" , Conn);
            SqlDataReader DR3 = Comm3.ExecuteReader();
```

And there is multiple results,how can I now move each of them in diffrent textbox (i already created textboxes? Till now i only managed to get same result into them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is normally how i do it....

```
   SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("my connection string");
    cn.Open();

    string sql = "select * from table where column = whatever";
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql,cn))
    {
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        while (dr.Read())
        {
            myTextBox1.Text = (string)dr["Column1"];
            myTextBox2.Text = (string)dr["Column2"];
            myTextBox3.Text = (string)dr["Column3"];
        }

        dr.Close();
    }

    cn.Close();
```

just make sure you are aiming the right column name while looping through them, and cast correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through each of the item in the Database table. Think of a `foreach` loop, where you simply just go through each item and work on it similarly.

Here is a sample for that,

```
// Create new SqlDataReader object and read data from the command.
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    // while there is another record present
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        // write the data on to the screen
        textBox.Text = reader[0];
    }
}
```

This will add the value of reader's first column (answer) to the textBox. Now make sure you're calling correct textBox to add the value to.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/823854/How-to-connect-SQL-Database-to-your-Csharp-program Do give this article a read.

Comment: I used your example, but for second text box textBox2.Text = reader[1]; i get error that Index was outside the bounds of the array. Does that means that SQL query returned only 1 result ?

Comment: Yes, indeed :-) it returned one record at 0 location. :-)